# Lie algebra of Lie subgroup

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group, and $H$ be a subgroup, which with the inherited group structure is a Lie group itself. Clearly $\mathfrak{h}$ is a subspace of $\mathfrak{g}$, but is it true that the Lie brackets on $\mathfrak{h}$ are the restriction of those on $\mathfrak{g}$?

Here is an argument for it:

- let $h \in H, \xi, \eta \in \mathfrak{h}$. Then $Ad^H_h(\xi)=T_e^H\phi^H_h[\xi]$. Here, I put $H$ as superscript to indicate that the quantities are computed w.r.t. $H$. Also, $\phi^H_h$ is conjugation by $h$, on $H$.
- we have that $\phi^H_h=\phi^G_h|_H$, and also, tangent maps on submanifold coincide with the tangent maps of the parent manifold. Hence, $Ad^H_h(\xi)=T_e^H\phi^H_h[\xi] = T_e^G\phi^G_h[\xi] = Ad^G_h(\xi)$
- differentiating at $e$, with respect to $h$, and testing at $\eta$, by the restriction argument of above, we get that indeed, $Ad^H(\xi, \eta) = Ad^G (\xi, \eta)$, and this is what I wanted

Is the reasoning correct? If yes/if the statement is true, is it possible to see it in a simpler way?
Thanks!

Comment: $H$ is a group, but not "a Lie algebra itself". If $H$ is a Lie subgroup, you could use the exponential map, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180082/lie-algebra-of-a-lie-subgroup).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Right, I made a typo, thanks for the reference.